# Why according to Vyasadeva, Shaiva-mata is inconsistent with the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, shiva, upanishads, brahma-sutras, vyasa

In our Vedas/ Upanishads, Vishnu/Narayana, Shiva/Rudra and Uma/Devi are all names of the Supreme Godhead. They same holds for different Puranas also.

Why does then Vyasadeva declare the Shaiva Mata as inconsistent with the Vedas in His Brahma-sutra by saying :"**patyur asamanjyasyaat**"?

Comment: Brahma Sutras is criticising Shaivite Agamas not the worship of Devi altogether

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury But why are shaivas also included?

Comment: Because Shaivite Agamas (except the Agamas of Kashmiri Shaivism) believe Brahman is only the efficient cause of the universe whereas Vedantins believe Brahman is both the efficient and material cause of the universe.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury pl write in detail in an answer

Comment: Ok, I might :).

Answer (score 5):

Vyasa isn't criticising the worship of Devi altogether in the Brahma Sutras but only criticising the Shaivite Agamas for its belief **that Brahman is only the efficient cause of the Universe since Vyasa believes that according to  the Vedas, Brahman is both the efficient and material cause of the universe**. This is what Vyasa says in the Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 of the Brahma Sutras regarding Shaivite Agamas:

> Topic-7: God Is Not a Mere Superintendent
>
> For the Lord there can be no creatorship, for that leads to incongruity.
>
> And (the incongruity arises) because of the impossibility of a relationship.
>
> And (the position is untenable) because of the impossibility of (Nature) coming under (His) direction. (Or) And (God cannot be proved), since no physical support (adhisthana) is possible for Him.
>
> Should it be argued that God will direct Nature like (a man directing) the organs, then it cannot be so, for that will result in God’s having experiences (of happiness, sorrow etc.). (Or) If a body, equipped with sense-organs, be assumed for God, (we say that) this is not possible; because of (consequent) experiences etc.
>
> God will be subject to finitude or loss of omniscience.

Comment: Could u make it a bit clearer please?

Comment: Where exactly is the contradiction in Saiva doctrines? And isnGod not the creator of the world?

Comment: As I said Shaiva believe Brahman is only the efficient cause of the universe. According to Vedanta, Brahman is both efficient and material cause of the universe.

Comment: If you can't understand what I mean by efficient and material causes, see this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes

Comment: Thnx.I have to find out what Saivas say first